# I am trying to figure out what is wrong with this Javascript code

Tags: javascript

```
function entertimesTable (timesTable,timesStart,timesEnd) 
{

    while (timesStart<=timesEnd)
    {

        document.write(timesTable + " * " + timesStart + "= " + timesTable*timesStart + "<br />");
        timesStart++;
    }
}

var timesTable;

    while ((timesTable=prompt("Please enter a table to use",-1) != -1)
    { 
        while (isNaN(timesTable) == true)
        {
            timesTable=prompt(timesTable + "is not a valid number, please retry", -1);
        }

        if (timesTable == -1)
        {
            break;
        }

        document.write("<br />The" + timesTable + " times table <br />");
        entertimesTable(timesTable,1,12);
    }
```

Its a simple function that does the times table for any number entered. A value of -1 will be invalid and I am also checking to make sure the user enter a valid number. It will not run. I have checked the syntax over and over again. This is my first question here.

Comment: what you are trying to do ? from where you are trying to call these methods ? what error you are facing ? can you post all require code to understand ?

Comment: what you're expecting in this answer? tell some example

Comment: syntax error on line 13

Comment: You've missed one extra paranthesis right before the `!=` in your `while`. Its working fine with that change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unmatched `(` in your while statement:

```
while ((timesTable=prompt("Please enter a table to use",-1) != -1) //3 left parens and 2 right parens
```

Modify that line to read:

```
while ((timesTable=prompt("Please enter a table to use",-1)) != -1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works! I feel so dumb, but good learning point for me.